# Python boto3 (AWS EC2) list Nested JSON Data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) to get a list of all instances like this.

```
id: i-fa512784, zone: us-east-1, state: running, name: redis, env: staging-db, app: php
id: i-fa112784, zone: us-east-1, state: running, name: redis, env: production, app: php
```

I would like to create a single string for all values per instance. I.e. each of instances should have own string with own keys. My goal is to put this data into Prometheus.

I have got stuck on parsing nested `"Tags": [` to get all values and output all of them into one string

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import boto3.utils
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='profile')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances(
   MaxResults=10,
)

for r in response['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        for tags in i['Tags']:
        print ('id:',i['InstanceId'], 'zone:',i['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'state:',i['State']['Name'])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: does the `print` statement dump the relevant info? I am not sure I understand what is the problem actually? Do you just need to create a single string for all the outputs?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia - I would like to create single string for all values per instance. I.e. each of instances should have own string with own keys. Thank you.

Comment: you can use `dictionary` and save the result into the dictionary based on the instance id to achieve what you want. I might be missing something here so please describe the error if any would help get more idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the code, you might need to change logic to append data to `tag_values_list`;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import boto3.utils

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='profile')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances(
    MaxResults=10,
)

for r in response['Reservations']:
    for i in r['Instances']:
        tag_values_list = []
        for tags in i['Tags']:
            for key, value in tags.items():
                tag_values_list.append(value)

        print('id:', i['InstanceId'], 'zone:', i['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'state:', i['State']['Name'],
              'tags:',
              tag_values_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is what I wished to have.